# Openssl: bad magic number issue

Tags: php, openssl

I encrypted a file using file_input_contents function:

```
file_input_contents('myfile',openssl_encrypt("This string was AES-128 / ECB encrypted.", "AES-128-ECB", "password"));
```

But I can't decrypt it using openssl command. Always getting "bad magic number" error.

I tried with this command:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -d -in myfile -out outputfile
```

Comment: Please provide a [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I didn't work with *perl*, and running that single line of code doesn't work.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using the same version of openssl when encrypting and decrypting? "[The default hash used to generate the key from the password changed between 1.0.2 and 1.1.0.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403320/112380)"